# How to retrieve parameter values from URL scheme

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have been working on an iPad app. We have setup the URL scheme (e.g. `myapp://?foo=1&bar=2`) for our app, so that when user clicks on link in a page, our app will open on iPad.

The problem is how to retrieve parameter values from URL scheme in the code?

There would be some way to retrieve it from the application entry point, but I have no idea of where the entry point of the application is in native code. We have developed the app through Unity3D. So is there a way to retrieve parameter values directly from a Unity app ?

Comment: :have u got the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this, maybe it'll help you:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
    NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
    NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);
    NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
    NSLog(@"query dict: %@", dict);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: How do you actually get the query values from Unity using C# or JS? Is it okay to assume we can just use PlayerPrefs and use the same key names as the parameter names in the URL?

Comment: But how do I do that? Do I create a plugin for that? And how am I supposed to retrieve the information from Unity C#?

Comment: Well how does this work...I have seen correct answer but no explanation...Can u explain in detail so that it could also help others...