# How to get values passed from URL scheme after opening the Unity app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, url-scheme

While searching I read this feature is not yet implemented in Unity may be in future version Unity might bring it.I got a link(coar://mylink.com/id=12345) when opened in Safari in my ipad it opened up my Unity app.How to get the id value 12345 from this link in Unity.Do we need plugin?Any other alternate simple method.

In player settings there is an option for supported URL schemes any use for our purpose.
There are some links I refered.[Link 1](https://calltheplummer.com/2018/04/17/ios-deep-linking-in-unity/) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099267/how-to-retrieve-parameter-values-from-url-scheme).In the second link where to place the code.Any step by step explanation will be helpful.

Another code I came across is

```
-(BOOL) application:(nonnull UIApplication *)application openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url options:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {


if([url.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"mygame://text="].location != NSNotFound){
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:url.absoluteString forKey:@"myurl"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
 }
```

From the above what I understand is the data is stored in playerprefs in the "myurl" key.But where exactly  to paste the code?No clue.How to retrieve the myurl using C# code.

Comment: Haven't the links answered your question?

Comment: @shingo....I would like a detailed explanation...From link2...I dont where to paste the code...Only the guy who asked and answered know it...because I havent seen that code.Are they using it as plugin or in some other files

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a plugin, and the tutorial in the first link I think is detailed enough.

For the second link, first build your project and unity will generate a Xcode project. Find **UnityAppController.mm**, may inside **Classes** folder, then add the function at the end of the file.

Another option is mentioned from the first link, create a mm file in your **Assets/Plugins/iOS/** folder, include **UnityAppController.h** then add **application handleOpenURL** function in it.

If you want to know how to pass the data from OC to C#, I have [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306250/raise-events-from-c-to-c-sharp-ios-to-unity/54434394#54434394) from another post.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code in UNityAppcontroller.mm towards end...but showing error  missing context for method declaration. now how to retrieve the data passed in the URL?

Comment: @shingo...Any idea using UnitySend message..?

Comment: The parameter `url ` is the url passed in. to use `UnitySendMessage` see my answer I made in another question, I've wrtten an example there.