# How to store iOS startup custom scheme data in NSUserDefaults to read from Unity

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

My app is developed using Unity3d (2018) and c#. The app is then build for iOS. Now, I want to use a custom scheme to launch my iOS app and provide some extra information:

```html
    some-custom-scheme://some-parameter=some-value
```

I've read in the [Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/start-ios-app-with-arguments-and-access-them-within-unity.99323/#post-1159896) that the best way to do this is to create a plugin in Unity and hook into the iOS startup pipeline as described in the forum post like this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*) launchOptions
{
    NSArray *keyArray = [launchOptions allKeys];
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]]!=nil) {
        NSURL *url = [launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:urlString forKey:@"url"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Within the app, I simply check the PlayerPrefs like this:

```cs
    var url = PlayerPrefs.GetString("url");
```

The url value however is empty. Iterating through the keys and alerting them in the app give two results: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey and UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey. Both irrelevant according [the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationlaunchoptionsannotationkey) which state that the data should be in the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsAnnotationKey key.

I've also read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54455339/how-to-get-values-passed-from-url-scheme-after-opening-the-unity-app) telling the poster to use the [openURL method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?language=occ).

I feel that I'm close but not there yet. What am I doing wrong and how can it be fixed? Which method is better? My approach using didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or the openURL method?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Method `openURL` need for opening link. `NSUserDefaults` - local storage for app.

if need save you color scheme need use `NSUserDefaults`, if need opening link for use new color scheme need use openURL.

Save to `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSString *urlScheme = @"some-custom-scheme://some-parameter=some-value";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:urlScheme forKey:@"url"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Read `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSString *loadUrlScheme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"url"];
//loadUrlScheme = some-custom-scheme://some-parameter=some-value
```

Comment: Thx @arts. I decided to use [this plugin](https://universaldeeplinking.imaginationoverflow.com) that will handle this for me.